# Update ToolStripMenu Properties at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu, toolstripmenu

how do we kinda "reroll" the properties checking after creating a ContextMenuStrip on c#?

I want to be able to disable some submenus on a config page, but after the ToolStripMenu is created I cannot change its properties on runtime, it only takes effect on the next run. Can you help me? I tried the refresh and invalidate methods with no success.

Comment: That should work.  Show us your code.

Answer (score 2):

Simple.
Make a contextMenuStrip will all the options, to remove them use

```
contextMenuStrip1.Items.Remove(contextMenuItem);
```

Comment: Gonna try with this. I somehow haven't thougth of that instead I was trying to keep it there while only changing its visibility. Hope this works.